# Let S be an arbitrary set and let $f_n : S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

> Let S be an arbitrary set and let $f_n : S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a
>   sequence of functions. If $f_n$ is increasing for all x $\in$ S and
>   $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, then f is increasing.

I'm trying to prove this theorem but the hypothesis is not clear for me. I've found this: [Prove that if the sequence of increasing functions $(f_n)$ converges to $f$, then $f$ is increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565585/prove-that-if-the-sequence-of-increasing-functions-f-n-converges-to-f-the) 
But I think that in my case, the hypothesis is saying that $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ for all x ∈ S and all n ∈ $\mathbb{N}$, which is simmilar to the hypothesis of *Dini's Theorem*.

Can you guys give me an ideia of how to prove this?

Comment: The way I'm reading your hypothesis is that for any $x$, $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$, and that the limit $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$ exists, and coincides with $f(x)$.  However it is not clear what it means for the function $f$ to be increasing unless $S$ is a set with a defined "ordering"-- for instance, what would it mean for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be "increasing"?  So perhaps try to clarify the statement of the theorem?

Comment: The result is untrue regardless of the interpretation of either "increasing in $n$ for fixed $x$" or "increasing in $x$ for fixed $n$."  Unless perhaps you want the latter interpretation (with a set $S$ for which this makes sense) and you also want to equate "increasing" with "nondecreasing." Overall, this is a poorly worded question: It is not clear what is being asked.

Comment: For example take $S=[0,1]$ and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by $f_n(x) = -x - 2^{-n}$, which is "increasing in $n$ for each fixed $x \in [0,1]$" but converges to $f(x)=-x$. It also not difficult to find examples of functions that are "increasing in $x \in [0,1]$ for each fixed $n$" but converge to a function that is nondecreasing but not increasing. [Here I assume "increasing" is the same as "strictly increasing"]

Comment: I was suspecting that the author made a mistake. Thanks for clarifying it, @Michael

Comment: Take $x<y$ since $f_n(x)\leq f_n(y)$ for all $n$ then $f(x)\leq f(y)$ so $f$ is increasing.